# General guidelines when constructing multiple REST apis on same server in Python

Tags: python, mysql, api, rest

I was tasked with building a framework to unify half a dozen of python webapps that share some common functionality between them.
The current setup consists of an apache web server, serving up a specific cgi script (for each app) that talks to a simple XMLRPC service (again, a different service for each app), which in turn runs db queries, writes files to disk, runs external scripts, etc..

The idea was to do away with redundant code (such as 6 different RPC services creating and managing 6 different connections to the same db, executing very similar queries, etc), as well as the whole XMLRPC thing. Also, keep things in python land and maintain a double layer of abstraction - the client-side app can't talk directly to the api that runs the queries and writes to the disk; it must talk to an intermediate api (currently the cgi scripts) that in turn talk to the processes that perform all the querying / disk writing.

Since this is my first major Python undertaking, I am somewhat struggling with finding the correct, DRY, modular and pythonic way of architecting this framework.

Ideally, I would like to construct a REST api that the code on the client-side (currently implemented in React.js) can talk to directly. 
This api should then be able to interface with another, internal REST api (currently, this is handled by the XMLRPC processes) that will do all the heavy-lifting (aforementioned db querying - perhaps using an ORM, executing tasks, writing files, and the like).

However, I'm not sure how I should implement the inter-api communication - should it be over HTTP (even if they're living on the same server?) or some other protocol I'm not aware of?

Also, how should I go about consolidating the common bits of code?

should there be a separate module / process that keeps a live connection to our db, and the disparate apis connect to it?

How can I implement an ORM with such a scheme, as I don't want new developers querying the db directly. I would like them to have an explicit model that they talk to instead.

I know this is a long and convoluted way of saying "I'm stuck", and for that I apologize and would happily provide more detail if asked, however what I'm asking for are more of a set of general guidelines:

- How should different REST apis (implemented using Flask + SQLAlchemy, for example) talk to each other, whether they live on the same server, or on different ones?
- How should I abstract away common tasks like connecting to a db into a separate process?
- Finally, what are some good, common-sense rules for keeping this whole thing modular?